# CORS error when calling AWS API Gateway from React application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm working on a React application that communicates with a backend API hosted on AWS API Gateway. Even after setting up CORS on the AWS side, I'm still encountering CORS errors when trying to make a request from my React application.

[image: My CORS config on the console]

I've also attached the `cors(corsOptions)` to each of my route handlers.

```
app.post("/user/create", cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  const result = await userService.createUser(req.body);
  res.json(result);
});

app.post("/user/login", cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const result = await userService.login(email, password, req);
  res.json(result);
});

app.get("/user/get", cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  const result = await userService.getUsers();
  console.log(result)
  res.json(result);
});

app.get("/user/byEmail/:email", cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  const result = await userService.getUser(req.params.email);
  res.json(result);
});

app.patch("/user/update/:email", cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  const result = await userService.updateUser(req.params.email, req.body);
  res.json(result);
});

app.delete("/user/remove/:email", cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  const result = await userService.deleteUser(req.params.email);
  res.json(result);
});
```

Despite my configurations, I still get the above error. I've verified that the API is being called correctly, and there are no typos or misconfigurations in the CORS setup (at least to my knowledge).

Any ideas on why I'm still getting this CORS error and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I even gave access to localhost through AWS cli

```
{
    "ApiEndpoint": "https://id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com",
    "ApiId": "bsqdkgnflh",
    "ApiKeySelectionExpression": "$request.header.x-api-key",
    "CorsConfiguration": {
        "AllowCredentials": false,
        "AllowMethods": [
            "*",
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "OPTIONS",
            "PATCH",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ],
        "MaxAge": 3000
    },
    "CreatedDate": "2023-09-18T20:23:48Z",
    "DisableExecuteApiEndpoint": false,
    "Name": "",
    "ProtocolType": "HTTP",
    "RouteSelectionExpression": "$request.method $request.path",
    "Tags": {
        "aws:cloudformation:stack-name": "",
        "aws:cloudformation:logical-id": "HttpApi",
        "aws:cloudformation:stack-id": "",        "STAGE": "dev"
    }
}
```

Comment: I got same problem when I use AWS Console for setting API Gateway. Just experience after enabled CORs, I need to deploy the stage every time I changed by click `Deploy API`. Hope it works with you